# Axiomatic Semantics - How to calculate a weakest precondition of a program

Tags: semantics, preconditions, formal-methods

Assuming the post-condition, how can I compute the weakest pre-condition of a program containing two statements?

For example :

```
 a=x;
 y = 0 
 {x = y + a}
```

Another example:

```
  y = x;
  y = x + x + y 
  {y = 3x ^ z> 0}
```

I tried to solve them but both questions resulted in pre-conditions or post-condition that are identical to the statement and I don't know if this is valid.

for example, the precondition of the last statement is "y=x" , thus it is the post condition of the preceding  statement which is " y=x" as well

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the rules of [Hoare Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) here.  Specifically, for the examples you have, you only need the rule for assignment:

> ---
>
> { P[E/x] } x = E { P }

Here, `P[E/x]` means take `P` and substitute (i.e. replace) all occurrences of `x` with `E`.  For example, if `P` is `x == 0` then `P[0/x]` gives `0 == 0`.

To calculate the weakest precondition, you start from the end and work backwards.  For your first example, we start with the last statement:

```
{ ??? } y = 0 { x == y + a }
```

The goal is to determine something suitable for `???`.  Applying our rule for assignment above, we can see that this is a solution:

```
{ x == 0 + a } y = 0 { x == y + a }
```

We can further simplify this to `{ x == a }`.  Then, we move on to address the statement before `y = 0`, and so on.